# Avoid repetition of view in android gridview

Tags: android-gridview

I am stuck at gridview.
I want an imageview below Gridview to handle click event of that.
Basically what i need is when click on this imageview button(here imageView_uparrow) it will slide up the layout which contains this gridview,
but when I add imageview(imageView_uparrow) below gridview(imageView_uparrow) in xml and run the project; gridview repeats that imageview on every grid icon.
 I want that imageview to be appeared once at the bottom.  Here is my XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/inside_gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:columnWidth="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_insidegrid"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_uparrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/drop_down_top_arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Last imageview i.e imageView_uparrow keep on repeating with the gridview items.
Please help me with this.. Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I got the solution..
i kept my imageView_uparrow in separate xml and image which i used to set as an icon of my grid separate xml.And just inflated and added that to the Layout.

My modified Grid Xml is here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/parentRel"
    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/inside_gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/transperant_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
         >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml file for ImageView(imageView_uparrow).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_up_arrow_for_gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"

         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code i use to inflate

```
Context context;
RelativeLayout rel;
ImageView upArrowImage;

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);





        context=this;
    View grid2;

    rel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentRel);

    animate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
    animate.setAnimationListener(this);



    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(14, 400, 0, 20);



    grid2=new View(context);
    grid2=inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_up_arrow_button,null);

    upArrowImage=(ImageView)grid2.findViewById(R.id.imageview_up_arrow);

    ((ViewGroup)upArrowImage.getParent()).removeView(upArrowImage);

    rel.addView(upArrowImage);
    upArrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.drop_down_arrow4);
    upArrowImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
```